# Does Test Target required to go on production in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it required to take Test case target in iOS application to production or it can be kept locally

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking. No target is included in production build. A target is a group of settings of the build system. It tells Xcode how to create the build, it is not included in the build. Neither production or debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Test Target does not get included in production builds. it does not even get included in debug builds.

In your build scheme, you can see, Test target is build only for Test.

[image]